# How to write binary and asci data into a file in python?

Tags: python, file, binary

I have this wired protocol I am implementing and I have to write binary and ASCII data into the same file, how can I do this at the same time or at least the result in the end will be the file with mixed asci and binary data ?

I know that `open("myfile", "rb")` does open myfile in the binary mode, except that I can't find a solution how to go about this!

Comment: You can just write ASCII data to a binary file still. Are you on Python 2 or 3 here?

Comment: @Martijn Python 2.7 can't use the 3 yet !

Comment: Then just write your ASCII data *directly*. The only difference between `w` and `wb` is how newlines are translated.

Comment: The end file will have ASCII and the binary data, the real question is how can the other program on the other part read the binary and the ASCII and see the difference ? Do you see what I mean here ?

Comment: That's a *different* question altogether. That's a file format design question. How will the other side know what the binary data *means*? ASCII is just binary data too; it's all zeros and ones in the end.

Comment: It's just a question of agreeing to a format. Perhaps you use initial bytes that encode what follows, with a length and a type. Take a look at the [GIF image format](http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/eecs20/sidebars/images/gif.html) for an example; that starts with several ASCII characters too, followed by binary data. Whatever reads that is coded to expect certain information at certain locations *because that's the agreed format*.

Comment: That is the case, I have the length and coding type for each bit, or each data entry, so to conclude, I open the file in binary mode and write the data and that is it ?

Comment: Exactly. If you already have a format, just write the data. ASCII is binary data too, just data that you can interpret as text.

Comment: FYI there is no \n or \r involved in the format. Thanks for the clarification and the GIF example makes more sense now, cheers !

Comment: But your binary data may well have a 0A or 0D byte in it, which *in text mode* would be interpreted as a newline or carriage return character. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54110/discussion-between-e-nouri-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Python 2, the *only* difference binary mode makes is how newlines are translated when writing; `\n` would be translated to the platform-dependant line separator.

In other words, just write your ASCII byte strings directly to your binary file, there is no difference between your ASCII data and the binary data as far as Python is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

What you write to a file is in fact "bytes". Python 2 or 3 (*Just that in Python2 it was `str` and we changed this to be more clear and explicit in Python 3 to `bytes`).

So:

```
with open("file.ext", "w") as f:
    f.write(b"some bytes")
```

Example:

```
bash-4.3$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Apr 28 2014, 00:50:45) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open("file.ext", "w") as f:
...     f.write(b"some bytes")
... 
>>> 
bash-4.3$ cat file.ext
some bytesbash-4.3$
```

Normally you would use an encoding if you are dealing with Unicode strings (*`str` in Python 3, `unicode` in Python 2*). e.g:

```
s = "Hello World!"

with open("file.ext", "w") as f:
    f.write(s.encode("utf-8"))
```

*Note:* As mentioned in the comments; `open(filename, "wb")` doesn't really do what you think it does - it just affects how newlines are treated.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @James, the "wb" only affects how the system handle new lines. I up voted your answer!