# Writing binary data to a file in Python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, binary

I am trying to write data (text, floating point data) to a file in binary, which is to be read by another program later. The problem is that this program (in Fort95) is incredibly particular; each byte has to be in exactly the right place in order for the file to be read correctly. I've tried using Bytes objects and .encode() to write, but haven't had much luck (I can tell from the file size that it is writing extra bytes of data). Some code I've tried:

```
mgcnmbr='42'
bts=bytes(mgcnmbr)
test_file=open(PATH_HERE/test_file.dat','ab')
test_file.write(bts)
test_file.close()
```

I've also tried:

```
mgcnmbr='42'
bts=mgcnmbr.encode(utf_32_le)
test_file=open(PATH_HERE/test_file.dat','ab')
test_file.write(bts)
test_file.close()
```

To clarify, what I need is the integer value 42, written as a 4 byte binary. Next, I would write the numbers 1 and 0 in 4 byte binary. At that point, I should have exactly 12 bytes. Each is a 4 byte signed integer, written in binary. I'm pretty new to Python, and can't seem to get it to work out. Any suggestions? Soemthing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781823/how-to-write-binary-and-asci-data-into-a-file-in-python)? I need complete control over how many bytes each integer (and later, 4 byte floating point ) is.

Thanks

Comment: Look into `struct.pack` in the stdlib.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834047/write-binary-string-in-binary-file-python-3-4/29855780#29855780

Answer (score 23):

You need the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html) module.

```
import struct

fout = open('test.dat', 'wb')

fout.write(struct.pack('>i', 42))
fout.write(struct.pack('>f', 2.71828182846))

fout.close()
```

The first argument in struct.pack is the format string.

The first character in the format string dictates the byte order or [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the data (Is the most significant or least significant byte stored first - big-endian or little-endian). Endianness varies from system to system. If ">" doesn't work try "<".

The second character in the format string is the data type. Unsurprisingly the "i" stands for integer and the "f" stands for float. The number of bytes is determined by the type. Shorts or "h's" for example are two bytes long. There are also codes for unsigned types. "H" corresponds to an unsigned short for instance.

The second argument in struct.pack is of course the value to be packed into the bytes object.

Here's the part where I tell you that I lied about a couple of things. First I said that the number of bytes is determined by the type. This is only partially true. The size of a given type is technically platform dependent as the C/C++ standard (which the struct module is based on) merely specifies *minimum* sizes. This leads me to the second lie. The first character in the format string also encodes whether the standard (minimum) number of bytes or the native (platform dependent) number of bytes is to be used. (Both ">" and "<" guarantee that the standard, minimum number of bytes is used which is in fact four in the case of an integer "i" or float "f".) It additionally encodes the [alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) of the data.

The [documentation on the struct module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html#format-strings) has tables for the format string parameters.

You can also pack multiple primitives into a single bytes object and realize the same result.

```
import struct

fout = open('test.dat', 'wb')

fout.write(struct.pack('>if', 42, 2.71828182846))

fout.close()
```

And you can of course parse binary data with struct.unpack.

Comment: That's the right thing.  Just one extra hint: use the `with` statement to avoid forgetting to `close`!

Comment: Beware,  symbol '>' into  struck.pack format chain is only for big-endian system, like Motorola 68000 or PowerPC G5, better to use "@" symbol that will create native format ( big-endian or little-endian),  Note you will create a file not portable to other plataforms.

Comment: This answer could be improved by saying why using the struct module is better than doing this another way (e.g. writing bytes directly)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want it in little-endian, you could do something like this to write 42 in a four byte binary.

```
test_file=open(PATH_HERE/test_file.dat','ab')
test_file.write(b'\xA2\0\0\0')
test_file.close()
```

A2 is 42 in hexadecimal, and the bytes `'\xA2\0\0\0'` makes the first byte equal to 42 followed by three empty bytes. This code writes the byte: 42, 0, 0, 0.

Your code writes the bytes to represent the character '4' in UTF 32 and the bytes to represent 2 in UTF 32. This means it writes the bytes: 52, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, because each character is four bytes when encoded in UTF 32.

Also having a hex editor for debugging could be useful for you, then you could see the bytes that your program is outputting and not just the size.

Comment: Yes, I understand that what was going on was it was writing each character as 4 byte values in UTF32, which is why I was getting 8 bytes (when I used little endian). However, this program will be used mainly as a converter which reads in data from files and transfers it, in the proper binary form, to another file. These files are incredibly huge, with hundreds of thousands of lines and values being written in. So I can't just type in the hex form for each value.

Comment: `chr(y&0xFF) + chr((y>>8)&0xFF) + chr((y>>(8*2))&0xFF) + chr((y>>(8*3))&0xFF)` should work for converting four byte ints where y is the number to be converted to string. It works by shifting down the number and entering the bytes one by one. I don't know how to do floating point numbers, though. -- If you know what bytes you want and are using python3, you could use `bytes([<1st byte>, <2nd byte>, <3rd byte>, <4th byte>])`. Replace <>'s with the bytes you want.

Answer (score -2):

In my problem [Write binary string in binary file Python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834047/write-binary-string-in-binary-file-python-3-4) I do like this:

```
file.write(bytes(chr(int(mgcnmbr)), 'iso8859-1'))
```